# Node.js: error GET http://undefined/socket.io/1/?t=1357634942292

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am running a Node.js app, while loading the url i am getting a error like below:

```
    GET http://undefined/socket.io/1/?t=1357634942292
```

on trying to send a message another error is produced , which is

Uncaught TypeError: Object # has no method 'send'

EDIT:
I have used a function

```
  client.broadcast.send({ announcement: client.sessionId + ' connected' });
```

now the error arising is 
TypeError:Property 'broadcast' of object # is not a function

Can anybody help me out what might have gone wrong in here?

Cheers
Jeev

Comment: i m having the same problem, what i m trying to do is that i want my page to load from domain 'a', and the page then connects to domain 'b' where node is running, the point is that socket.io.js is on domain 'a' and i m getting this error!
if you found the solution please help me too. thanks

Answer (score -1, accepted):

[refer this](http://psitsmike.com/2011/09/node-js-and-socket-io-chat-tutorial/)
it will be helpfull for you.
Thanks

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.

Answer (score 0):

how about sharing the client initialisation code?

i guess your io.connect method is called wrong. you do it like `io.connect();` where it needs to be: `io.connect("http://yourdomain.tld");`

Comment: when i try with that i am getting a error in cmd prompt as TypeError:Property 'broadcast' of object #<socket> is not a function.

Comment: well.. what i mean is.. are you following the instructions you can read at http://socket.io ?

Comment: wel,yes i tried now i am getting more errors, could you please tel me how to open a chat with you as longer discussions are not allowed here? i am totally new to this

Comment: I am still not able to figure out the error in here?? is it that it's using different version of socket.io??

Comment: well, i just re-installed node and socket.io into a new folder and it all seems to works fine now.Thanks alot

Answer (score 0):

did you find the awnser for this? My best tip is to check that you specified io.connect('localhost:6666') or wherever you set up your site, as in [that question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15437156/http-domain-local-socket-io-1-t-1363363318728-moved-permanently)