# http://domain.local/socket.io/1/?t=1363363318728 moved permanently

Tags: node.js, socket.io

I have a CodeIgniter driven website.
I want to implement a web chat based on NodeJS+Socket.IO.

I have the chat working on other local domain at the main folder, but when I moved it to the CodeIgniter it stopped working. I guess it is because I changed the folders relation to suit CodeIgniter's structure.

I have placed the `node_modules` at root folder.
The `server.js` is inside the `node_modules` folder.
The client javascript `chat.js` is placed in folder `public/js`
My view file is in `application/views/chat.php`
This view is accessible at location `domain.local/conversation/room`

When I open the page in the console I see:

`http://domain.local/socket.io/1/?t=1363363318728 moved permanently`

Comment: do you know what ?t= refers to in a socket.io connection?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found what's wrong.

The connection script was pointing to
`var socket = io.connect('http://domain.local/node:8080')`
and it should be to the root domain
`var socket = io.connect('http://domain.local:8080')`